# How do I remove multiple characters from the beginning of strings in a list?

Tags: dplyr, stringr

Say I have the following string -

```
some_list <- c("cs_m_string1", "m_string2", "string3_d", "string4_h")
```

I want to be able to specify a list of characters to remove from the beginning of the strings in `some_list`. For example I want to specify a list such as `remove_beg <- c("cs_m_", "m_")` , to remove from the beginning of strings in the list and get this result -

`"string1" "string2" "string3_d" "string4_h"`

Additionally in a separate operation I want to be able to do the same thing for characters at the end of the strings, so specify a list such as `remove_end <- c("_d", "_h")`, and get the this result -

`"cs_m_string1" "m_string2" "string3" "string4"`

I can use `some_list %>% str_remove_all("^cs_m_")` to remove 1 character at a time, but I have a large list and want to specify several characters to remove at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to collapse your list of characters that you want to remove into one string with `paste0`, then you can directly put that into `str_remove_all`.

```
library(stringr)

remove_list <- c("cs_m_", "m_")
paste_list <- paste0("^", remove_list, collapse = "|")

some_list %>% 
  str_remove_all(paste_list)

#[1] "string1"   "string2"   "string3_d" "string4_h"
```

Comment: i think you mean `remove_list=c(...)`